# Marathon Scaling is not adhering to Constraint Parameter

Tags: docker, scaling, mesos, marathon

I am facing some issue with marathon application scaling. I am deploying application with Marathon Constraint and it is running fine on the specific box. But when i try to scale the application it is not following the constraint and it is scaling on its own on available box.

```
"id": "app-abc", 
  "cpus": 1, 
  "mem": 256.0,
  "instances": 1, 
  "constraints": [["hostname", "LIKE", "10.10.10.123"]]
```

While scaling the application, its scaling to the box - 10.10.10.245

Please help me understand what should I check to fix this.

Comment: Interesting issue. Can you share more details? What Marathon version are you using? How do you perform scaling? What is the output from `/v2/apps` before and after scaling? I'm not sure but maybe you need to escape dots. `LIKE` accepts regexp and that may be an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the CLUSTER operator as described in https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/constraints.html#cluster-operator

E.g.

```
 "constraints": [["hostname", "CLUSTER", "10.10.10.123"]]
```